# ag-grid prevent filter submit

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

When a filter is changed in ag-grid for the infinite model it detects the change and updates the grid using the datasource getRows.  Before it does this it clears the grid.  Because the data I am using is expensive to fetch I would like to be able to set multiple filters without clearing the existing data and then fetch when a button is clicked.  Is it possible to disable the filter update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that pinning rows excludes them from filtering so I am doing that.  The makers of the lib, ag-grid suggested using the blockLoadDebounceMillis property, which is probably a cleaner way to accomplish the same thing.